# What is the relationship between entanglement and quantum correlation?

Tags: entanglement, correlations

What is the relationship between **entanglement** and **quantum correlation**? Are they synonym?

Sometimes, these two words look like synonym; people use one word to explain another,

> These states are not a simple tensor product of the states of each qubit but rather a superposition that describes **quantum correlations (entanglement)** between the qubits.

On the other hand, it seemed we need to distinguish these two words,

> If you read a randomly selected nontechnical account of **quantum entanglement**, you will likely be told that measuring a particle in one place can instantly change another particle elsewhere, no matter the distance between the two. Surprisingly, this is something that Paul Halpern never claims in his new book, *Synchronicity*. ...to connote an “acausal connecting principle.” **Quantum correlations**, in Halpern’s view, are a special case of synchronicity.
>
> Excerpted from [*Quantum correlations at a distance needn’t necessarily be “spooky”*
> 1st paragrah](https://blogs.sciencemag.org/books/2020/09/22/synchronicity/)

Moreover, is the following expression correct? ([http://memoirs.is.kochi-u.ac.jp/Vol26/MemoirsF26-6.pdf 2.3.2](http://memoirs.is.kochi-u.ac.jp/Vol26/MemoirsF26-6.pdf), I translated it into English)

> The **quantum correlation** MUST exist in the entanglement state; however, even if there is a quantum correlation, it cannot be called **entanglement**. For example, when the relationship between qubits A and B is $|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0_A0_B\rangle+|1_A1_B\rangle)$, which cannot be separated by the tensor product. In other words, it is an **entanglement** state, and there exists a **quantum correlation**.
>
> After measuring, this state changes to $|0_A0_B\rangle$ or $|1_A1_B\rangle$. There is a quantum correlation in $|0_A0_B\rangle$ or $|1_A1_B\rangle$ state, but it is no longer an **entanglement** state.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure the term quantum correlation has a consistent definition across the literature. In nonlocality it is most often used to mean a probability distribution that could have arisen from measurements on some quantum systems.

Comment: handwavily, I'd say entanglement is a property of a *bipartite* state: $\rho$ is entangled if it cannot be written in a specific way. *Correlations* are a property of the probability distribution resulting from measuring a state with a given measurement. *Quantum correlations* refers to correlations which cannot be produced with "classical" states and measurements. However, what precisely "nonclassical/quantum" means might depend on the context. E.g. when studying nonlocality "quantum correlations" are those that cannot be written as local deterministic behaviours.